# can't open / format SD card

Tags: windows-10, formatting, sd-card, raw, open

**Situation** :

1. was moving files from phone (usb cable) to pc
2. files moved succefully
3. after ejecting, the card was filled with many large unknown files (+4gb per file). The names were weird symbols.
4. restarted the phone, didn't detect memory
5. inserted a reader in the laptop, couldn't open
6. quick formated succefully, can open memory
7. tried recovering files using (EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard, MiniTool Power Data Recovery 8.7, iCare Data Recovery Free).
8. recovered data succefully
9. tried moving some of the recoverd files onto memory but couldn't
10. can't open memory again neither can format it

---

**Tried solutions** : *attached some outputs*

- [Quick format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acLJp.png)
- [Disk manager format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Yeu.png)
- Android system format
- [Diskpart format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjToJ.png)
- Manjaro linux (gparted) and normal format
- [3rd party software format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo72B.png) (EaseUS Partition Master 13.8 / MiniTool Partition Wizard / AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition 8.7)
- 3rd part software partition recovery (EaseUS Partition Recovery 8.5 / [Find and Mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7n3g.png))
- Command line test ([chkdsk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwwKP.png) / [testdisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdWeS.png))
- Write protection disable (EaseUS Tools M Beta / diskpart)
- Change (Drive letter, phone, pc, reader, usb port)

**EDIT** :

[clean command + create partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ2oN.png) didn't work.

---

```
info :
memory : LEXAR 120 GB
PC : tomahawk computer / dell latitude e6410 laptop
OS : windows 10 x64 / manjaro linux
phone : infinix zero 4 plus (x602)
```

Comment: This looks like a broken SD card ... did you try the `clean` command in `diskpart`?

Comment: Yes I tried. `DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.`

Comment: The disk should have no partition after cleaning it, unlike what's shown in the picture you uploaded. Can you create a partition in diskpart after cleaning the disk? Did you try with the NTFS format instead of FAT?

Comment: it still has the partition after cleaning. check the edit section in main post for a snapshot

Comment: .., and try formatting it with your phone.

Comment: i tried. with no luck